# vba .cells.value application defined or user defined error

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I am using the following code to count the occurrence of the combination in each row of worksheet :

> 0
>
> 1

However the line `.Cells(r + 1, c).Value = activation_count` is causing runtime error 1004: application defined or user defined error

Can anyone see where the problem is coming from?

```
Sub count_activations() 'to count 01 combinations in sheet

Dim row As Long
Dim col As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Integer
Dim activation_count As Integer

    With Sheets("Link_TSR 10yr_Year 1_RTC1 Whitl")
    
        row = Range("A:A").Rows.Count
        col = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        
        For c = 3 To col 
            activation_count = 0
            
                For r = 4 To row
                
                    If Cells(r, c).Value = 0 And Cells(r - 1, c).Value = 1 Then
                    activation_count = activation_count + 1
                    End If
                Next r
                    .Cells(r + 1, c).Value = activation_count
        Next c
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: You loop to the last row on the sheet, then try to write to the row below that, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Ah yes it should be the last used row - obvious mistake! Thanks

Comment: `row = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row` will also make the loop smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies I forgot to post the corrected code earlier.

Previously, I was counting all rows in the sheet where I wanted to count all of the rows with data in. Cheers Davesexcel for pointing out the obvious error!

```
 Sub count_activations() 'to count 01 combinations in sheet

    Dim row As Long
    Dim col As Long
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim activation_count As Integer

        With Sheets("Link_TSR 10yr_Year 1_RTC1 Whitl")
        row = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row 'counts only the used cells in column A
        col = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For c = 3 To col 
        activation_count = 0

            For r = 4 To row

                If Cells(r, c).Value = 0 And Cells(r - 1, c).Value = 1 Then
                activation_count = activation_count + 1
                End If
            Next r
                .Cells(r + 1, c).Value = activation_count
        Next c

    End With

End Sub
```